# Жизненный цикл local reference в JNI

Tags: android, jni, native

Не смог разобраться с local reference (локальная ссылка) при работе в native коде через JNI. Я знаю, что локальные ссылки можно преобразовывать в глобальные (NewGlobalRef). Я знаю, что локальные ссылки можно удалять самому (DeleteLocalRef). Но объясните, плиз, непонятные мне моменты:

1) Если мы из java-кода вызываем native-функцию и получаем какой-то jobject как параметр native-функции, то он получается как локальная ссылка и эта ссылка удаляется после выхода из той самой native-функции. Это мне понятно.

2) Если мы из java-кода вызываем native-функцию и получаем jobject внутри этой native-функции как результат вызова одного из java-методов, то он тоже является локальной ссылкой. Но каков жизненный цикл данной локальной ссылки и кто, когда и каким образом за него отвечает? Связан ли жизненный цикл локальной ссылки с выходом из native-функции в которой она получена или нет? Вроде бы виртуальная машина ничего не знает о том, где именно ссылка была получена и поэтому жизненный цикл ссылки не связан с данной native-функцией? Получается абсолютно все локальные ссылки полученные таким образом нужно удалять самому? Или же внутри объекта "локальная ссылка" имеется какой-то "деструктор", в котором, например, неявно вызывается DeleteLocalRef для этой ссылки при удалении объекта "локальная ссылка" в native-коде?

3) Если мы из java-кода вызываем native-функцию и внутри неё запускаем native-поток и уже внутри него получаем jobject из java-метода, то отличается ли эта ситуация и жизненный цикл локальной ссылки от пункта 2?

4) Что такое и с чем связана local reference table? Она относится к любому потоку или только к native-потоку или к чему-то ещё?